# How can I write a drop down box in JSF?

Tags: jsf, drop-down-menu

How can I write a drop down box in JSF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
To select one option
<h:selectOneMenu id="list1">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1"></f:selectItem>
</h:selectOneMenu>

To select multiple option
 <h:selectManyListbox id="list">
 <f:selectItems value="#{optionBean.optionList}"></f:selectItem>
 </h:selectManyListbox>
```